# How to fix Python Django TypeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple model class which I want to return the the value for a field in my Django Admin.

Error Logs from terminal

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

models.py

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    error = models.ForeignKey(Error, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.error + " fixed by " + self.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out the solution. Replacing the Solution Model Class to the below code snippet will fix the error.

models.py

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    error = models.ForeignKey(Error, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Solution for " + str(self.error) + " by " + str(self.user)
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution came just in time

Answer (score 1):

It is often better to make use of [*string formatting* [pep-498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) or [*literal string interpolation* [pep-498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), since this is a more robust tool that will automatically call `str(…)`. Finally it is also more readable:

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    error = models.ForeignKey(Error, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.error} fixed by {self.user}'
```